# Why does `=` in Python's format function inserts padding after the prefix?

Tags: python, formatting

Why does the numeric alignment option `=` inserts padding after the prefix `0x` in Python's `format` function:

```
>>> "{: =+#8x}".format(4)
'+0x    4'
```

i.e. why is the output `'+0x    4'` and not `'+    0x4'`?

The docs are a bit ambiguous saying:

> Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the digits.

Technically `0` in `0x` is a digit, but `0x` is treated in the same way as a sign in the above example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it is mostly useful with *zero padding*

Currently:

```
>>> "{:0=+#8x}".format(4)
'+0x00004'
```

But would you prefer: `'+00000x4'` ? I don't think so, as this isn't even a valid number

```
   +00000x4
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```